# Selecting lines using the parent as a filter

Tags: sql

I have a 'Account_move_line' table

```
'Account_move_line'
ID      Code
1       9601
2       9602
...
```

The Code from 'Account_move_line' can have a parent

```
'Analytic_account'
ID      Code        Parent
1       5627        NULL
2       9601        5627
3       9601        5627
4       9603        5627
...
```

I have an existing query that starts from 'Account_move_line' where i select the a 'Account_move_line'.code to generate the report.

But now i want to start the report selection from the parent_code which is not in the 'Account_move_line'.

Example. Make a report from 5627 . I would like to keep my general structure for the report which starts from 'Account_move_line'

Is the a way to do something like this?:

Select ID, Code from 'Account_move_line' where 'Account_move_line'.code in children_from_id(5627)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM 'Account_move_line' where 'Account_move_line'.Code IN ( SELECT 'Analytic_account'.Code from 'Analytic_account' where 'Analytic_account'.Parent = 5627 )
```

This should work if I understood well what you need.

E : The subquery below selects all Codes from Analytic_account with the parent 5627.

```
SELECT 'Analytic_account'.Code from 'Analytic_account' where 'Analytic_account'.Parent = 5627
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach using `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT l.* FROM Account_move_line l
INNER JOIN Analytic_account a ON a.Code=l.Code
WHERE a.Parent=5627
```